# AWS schedule lambda functions without cloudwatch events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there an alternative to schedule lambda functions without cloudwatch?

Tks

Comment: Why do you not with to use an Amazon CloudWatch Event rule to schedule the AWS Lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aws event bridge to do event scheduling to trigger your lambda.  https://console.aws.amazon.com/events

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will analyze this alternative.

Comment: Did you find any other alternative way to trigger lambda without aws cloudwatch event or bridge ?